# MYSQL Join with Null value returned

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a query thats joining two table, using the GROUP_CONCAT to get a comma separated list which is then being mapped to an array in an object

**SQL:**

```
    $sql = "SELECT *,
            GROUP_CONCAT(climb_attributes.attribute_id) as climb_attributes
            FROM climbs
            LEFT JOIN climb_attributes ON
            (climbs.id = climb_attributes.climb_id)
            GROUP BY climb_id
            ORDER BY climbs.id";
```

**PHP**

```
$all_climb_profiles[$climb->id]->attributes = explode(",", $climb->climb_attributes);
```

Nearly working perfectly, except I currently only get back results IF the climb_attributes table contains the climb id. Essentially a climb can still exist even if it doesn't have any attributes, but at the moment it **has to** have an attribute to be returned in the results.

I also need to join it to another table to get the attribute name for the attribute id...if you can help with that as well that would be great, I'm hoping I can figure that out though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should not be using `*` to select from all tables when using `group by`.  You can safely take all the columns from the `climb` table.

The problem is that you are aggregating on a column in the *second* table, rather than the first.  And, it is `NULL` if there is no match.  So, a better query is:

```
SELECT c.*, GROUP_CONCAT(ca.attribute_id) as climb_attributes
FROM climbs c LEFT JOIN
     climb_attributes ca
     ON c.id = ca.climb_id
GROUP BY c.id
ORDER BY c.id;
```

EDIT:

If you want to list the strings, then something like this should work:

```
SELECT c.*, GROUP_CONCAT(a.name) as climb_attributes
FROM climbs c LEFT JOIN
     climb_attributes ca
     ON c.id = ca.climb_id LEFT JOIN
     attributes a
     ON ca.attribute_id = c.id
GROUP BY c.id
ORDER BY c.id
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you, and for the explanation as well. Can you help me link the ca.attribute_id to a third table containing the name for the attribute_id, its just has id and attribute_name column

Comment: I've been trying to figure work out how I can turn the ca.attribute_id into the actual value of the attribute_id, which is stored in a third table which just contains id and attribute columns, so rather than just a list of numbers, I get the actual value associated with the number.